# How can i turn this into an array

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, loops

Hey so basically i was told to write a very basic chatter bot program for part one of my assignment, and for part two i now need to create an array with the code i already wrote yielding the same results but i have no idea how to go about it. Iv looked a tons of videos online but they only talk about int array and for my project i need a string array that can take in user input, scan/search for a key word in the user input then display  "JOptionPane" to get another user input and check for key words and so on.
ill show you my current code:

```
enter code here      
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ChatterBot {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    String input = "";
    String maths = "";
    String science = "";
    String chemFact = "";
    String bioFact = "";
    String zooFact = "";
    String algFact = "";
    String yes = "Well good for you";
    String no = "You learn something new everyday :)";
    input = JOptionPane
            .showInputDialog("Pick one of the subjects listed to learn a fun fact (english, science, maths) ");

    if (input.contains("science")) {
        science = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                "What kind of science fact woukd you like to know about? (chem, Biology, Zoology)");
    }

    else if (input.contains("maths")) {
        maths = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                "What kind of maths fact would you like to know about? (algebra, fractions, division) ");
    }
    if (maths.contains("algebra")) {
        algFact = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                "\"Did you know a mathematician who specializes in algebra is called an algebraist? (yes or no)\"");
    }
    if (algFact.contains("yes")) {
        System.out.println(yes);
    } else if (algFact.contains("no")) {
        System.out.println(no);
    }

    if (science.contains("chem")) {
        chemFact = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                "Did you know If you pour a handful of salt into a full glass of water the water level will actually go down rather than overflowing the glass? (yes or no)");
    }

    if (chemFact.contains("yes")) {
        System.out.println(yes);
    } else if (chemFact.contains("no")) {
        System.out.println(no);
    }

    else if (science.contains("biology")) {
        bioFact = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Did you know The brain itself cannot feel pain? (yes or no)");
    }

    if (bioFact.contains("yes")) {
        System.out.println("Well good for you");
    } else if (bioFact.contains("no")) {
        System.out.println("You learn something new everyday :)");
    }

    else if (science.contains("zoology")) {
        zooFact = JOptionPane
                .showInputDialog("Did you know butterflies have taste receptors on their feet? (yes or no)");
    }

    if (zooFact.contains("yes")) {
        System.out.println("Well good for you");
    } else if (zooFact.contains("no")) {
        System.out.println("You learn something new everyday :)");
    }
    if (input.contains("?")) {
        System.out.println("I will be asking the questions");
    }

}
```

}

Comment: You create a string array the same as an int array but use `String` as the type. It's not clear to be what the specific issue is.

Comment: [scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) see here the scanner class which you can use to scan your input for key words as well.

Answer (score 0):

An example of how to use a string array is:

```
String[] facts = new String[]{"fact1", "fact2", "fact3"};

fact1 = facts[0];

System.out.println(fact1);
```

To keep the types of facts separate, you will need multiple arrays.

A suitable data structure for storing all facts, but keeping each fact type separate is a Map.